# Can't get sourcemap to work

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, web, dotless

I am trying to get my implementation of sourcemaps to work with dotless.

I have pulled [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) and added sourcemap[(1)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)[(2)](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit) generation to it. The problem is that even though I deliver my css-file with the corresponding

- `SourceMap` : `Main.less.map` HTTP-Header and
- `X-SourceMap` : `Main.less.map` HTTP-Header and have at the end of my css file the comment
- `/*@ sourceMappingUrl=Main.less.map */` and
- `/*@ sourceURL=Main.less.map */`
- chrome canary (Version 27.0.1424.0)

chrome doesn't care at all. It goes without saying, that I have enabled the `"Enable source maps"`-swtich in the console-settings. The content-types for all files seem to be fine too. (double checked) - For the source-map-location I have tried the full url as well as a relative notation of the address - but nothing seems to work...

Chrome doesn't even request the map file from the server. Any ideas? Did I miss something?

Cheers, Corelgott

Comment: I took a look at the chrome source that's used to parse the tag within  stylesheets: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/search?q=loadSourceMapForStyleSheet&origq=loadSourceMapForStyleSheet&btnG=Search+Trunk

So my line needs to match the regex of: /^\/\*@ sourceMappingURL=([^\s]+)\s*\*\/$/ (js) - but even adapting my line and checking that it matches the code I deliver, (I extracted the code and created a little test-app), it still doesn't work. Chrome doesn't even request the map file from the server... any clues here?

Answer (score 0):

Currently CSS source maps in Chrome only support Sass, not LESS.  Even this support is behind a "Developer Tools Experiments" flag: (see [Addi Osmani's post](https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/5qxt7Bu3Eay) on the subject for more info).

A Mozilla team is also working on CSS Source maps for Sass, LESS and Stylus, although I don't know how active the project is.  You can track their progress here:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/DevTools/Features/CSSSourceMap